# How can I open the Applications and Files lenses from command line?

Tags: 11.10, scripts, default-programs

Can someone tell me if there is a application or script that can be called from the terminal screen that will bring up the Find Applications or Find Files window that comes up when you click the More Apps an Find Files button in the Dash Home?

Thanks in advance for any comments suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It's never safe to publish your email address on an open web site. I've removed it from the post. If you're sure you want it to be publicly visible, you can [undo this revision](http://askubuntu.com/faq#editing). You can also subscribe to this question per mail [on the bottom of this site](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PGqGf.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the package `xdotool`, then you can:

- Open the Applications lens:

  ```
  xdotool keydown super sleep 0.1 key a keyup super
  ```
- Open the Files lens:

  ```
  xdotool keydown super sleep 0.1 key f keyup super
  ```
- Open the Music lens:

  ```
  xdotool keydown super sleep 0.1 key m keyup super
  ```